# Java Sum Of Two Dice - Will This Code Give Above A 6?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public class SumOfTwoDice 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int SIDES = 6;
        int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * SIDES);
        int b = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * SIDES);
        int sum = a + b;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

I've taken this code from the book "Introduction to Programming with Java" by Sedgewick on their online website.

I just have a question as to whether `a` or `b` could possibly be above `6` if by chance `Math.random()` is `1.0`? Or am I wrong on this?

1.0 * 6 + 1 = 7?

Comment: `Math.random()` will not return 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.random()` can't return 1.0, so `a` or `b` can't be 7.

```
/**
 * Returns a <code>double</code> value with a positive sign, greater 
 * than or equal to <code>0.0</code> and less than <code>1.0</code>.  <-----------
 * Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) 
 * uniform distribution from that range. 
 * 
 * <p>When this method is first called, it creates a single new
 * pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression
 * <blockquote><pre>new java.util.Random</pre></blockquote> This
 * new pseudorandom-number generator is used thereafter for all
 * calls to this method and is used nowhere else.
 * 
 * <p>This method is properly synchronized to allow correct use by
 * more than one thread. However, if many threads need to generate
 * pseudorandom numbers at a great rate, it may reduce contention
 * for each thread to have its own pseudorandom-number generator.
 *  
 * @return  a pseudorandom <code>double</code> greater than or equal 
 * to <code>0.0</code> and less than <code>1.0</code>.
 * @see     java.util.Random#nextDouble()
 */
public static double random();
```

Comment: I read the docs for Math.random() and I could have swore it said between 0.0 and 1.0 before. I just read it again. Today's been a really long night.

Answer (score 1):

No, [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) will never return 1. It has an *inclusive* lower bound of 0, but an *exclusive* upper bound of 1.0. From the documentation - emphasis mine:

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and **less than** 1.0.

Now given that this is floating point maths, you still need to consider whether there's some value less than 1 such that when multiplied by 6, the closest representable double is 6 rather than some value just below 6... but I don't *believe* that's a problem here.

It would still be clearer to use `java.util.Random` though....

```
private static final int SIDES = 6;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int a = random.nextInt(SIDES) + 1;
    int b = random.nextInt(SIDES) + 1;
    int sum = a + b;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: `(1 - 2**-53) * 6` rounds to a double less than `6`, so it's fine.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Right - it's the sort of thing I *suspect* will be fine, but never quite trust without doing the maths :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Math.random()` method doesn't return 1.0 since it has its bounds at 0.0 upto but not including 1.0 and multiplying by 6 and adding 1 to it i.e `(Math.random()*6)+1` will return values from 1 to 6 after type-casted to `(int)`.

Also the variable sides could have been declared as final

```
private static int SIDES = 6;
```

Comment: Where did you get the bound 0.9 from?

Comment: the bounds 0.0 upto but not including 1.0

Comment: and what about 0.95, or 0.991, ... ?

Comment: are all variations of 0.9 and my example shows it to 1 precision

Comment: Thats not the common meaning of a bound. Saying that there is a bound at 0.9 is plain wrong. And by the way 0.99 shown to one digit precision is 1.0.

Comment: OK my bad, thanks for pointing that out. And i repeat, the bounds 0.0 upto but not including 1.0

Answer (score 0):

random() may produce values close enough to 1, however they will always be LESS than 1.
The issue here is the cast to (int) from a positive double. The result will always be less than 6, varying in the set of {0,1,2,3,4,5}. So the answer is NO, neither a nor be can ever by 7.
Hope this helps.

To prove, run the following code:

```
    double x=0.99;
    System.out.println((int)(6*x));
```

Play with the x value, no matter how close it is to 1, you will still get 5 or less printed.